# Why we use disk_logs and what are the advantages of using disk_log for a database?

Tags: database, indexing, erlang

I have to create database flat files, my supervisor said me that I have to create disk_log module(We use Erlang) for the database but I can't understand why I have to use disk_log and what are the advantages we got from it. I read Erlang docs about disk_log but I can't understand it also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This related to Erlang programming language. It has a module called "disk-log". I got following details from its manual.

---

disk_log is a disk based term logger which makes it possible to efficiently log items on files. Two types of logs are supported, **halt logs** and **wrap logs**. A halt log appends items to a single file, the size of which may or may not be limited by the disk log module, whereas a wrap log utilizes a sequence of wrap log files of limited size. As a wrap log file has been filled up, further items are logged onto to the next file in the sequence, starting all over with the first file when the last file has been filled up. For the sake of efficiency, items are always written to files as binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with disk_log, but quickly skimming over it, it seems like it would be used as a journal. You can get some speed improvement and robustness with journals. Assuming that the database writes its state to disk every n ticks, you get speed but no robustness. Less file I/O, but between those ticks, you have unsaved data in case of a crash. Writing to journal the events that would cause database state changes, is probably quicker than writing the database state changes, but still allowing you to recover in case of a crash.

Comment: how it improve the speed, does it like an indexing file in a database?

Comment: No, it reduces the times the database itself needs to write its contents to disk (slow IO), instead it appends to a separate file, not affecting the database response. Whereas indexes help by reducing searching, journal helps by reducing writing.